# How to use updateHandler with HKAnchoredObjectQuery in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

In my application I want to fetch HealthKit data using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`. I've written code which is returning added and deleted data but i want to set `UpdateHandler` with `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` so, when data added/deleted in HealthKit then I get notification in app.

```
-(void)AnchoredObjectQueryTest
{
    HKSampleType *sampleType1 =
    [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];

    HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query =
    [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc]
     initWithType:sampleType1
     predicate:nil
     anchor: HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor
     limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit
     resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * query,
                      NSArray<HKSample *> * sampleObjects,
                      NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * deletedObjects,
                      HKQueryAnchor *newAnchor,
                      NSError * error) {

         if (error) {

             // Perform proper error handling here...
             NSLog(@"*** An error occured while performing the anchored object query. %@ ***",
                   error.localizedDescription);

             abort();
         }

       anchor = newAnchor;


         for (HKQuantitySample *sample in sampleObjects) {
             NSLog(@"Add : %@", sample);
         }

         for (HKDeletedObject *sample in deletedObjects) {
              NSLog(@"Delete : %@", sample);
         }


     }];


     [healthStore executeQuery:query];
}
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you have already written.

Comment: Hi Allan, I've added code. Can you please check and let me know where i need to changes. I appreciate if you share sample code in objective c.

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate and execute your HKAnchoredObjectQuery and it will run once, calling back to the block specified in the *handler* **parameter**.

Instantiate the query and set the *updateHandler* **property** on the query, then execute the query. The query runs the first time as before, calling back to the *handler* **parameter** you provided at instantiation; the query runs subsequently when results are added or deleted to the store and calls back to your *updateHandler*.

In my case, I use the same block for the handler parameter and the updateHandler property.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you very much for your reply.  Is it possible to share sample code for easy understanding. I've added sample code.

Comment: My code is in Swift. But the change needed to yours is simple. Just before [healthStore executeQuery:query]; you need to set the updateHandler property of your query to a block/closure to handle subsequent results. That block could be the same one you used for the resultsHandler parameter when instantiating your query.